# Don't know how to convert an Angular Web App made with nodejs to windows exe

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm a complete noob at programming with nodejs.
I'm developing an webapp with angularjs with this structure:

[image]

So, when I run the command *"nw ."* with the prompt command my application loads correctly.

All I want now is transform all this structure on an single Windows executable for distribute it for my customers.

I'm looking for any solutions like Bat to Exe, APPJS, and a lot of others. But I do not have any success either.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to need to looking at use a tool like ng-template to build everything into a single package or distributing a basic web server along with your site in order to make things work.

This is mainly due to the issue with the browser not allowing XHR requests from disk as AngularJS runs and request the various html files as your views change.

The best thing is to look using a tool like ng-template to compile all of the html partials into a single .js file that can be loaded from disk along with your AngularJS app. This way AngularJS will load all your partials into the $template cache and won't have to make any XHR calls to load them.

The other possibility is to look at something simple like the Cassini Web server or something similar that you can add to your directory and launch with a simple batch file. I say this because you are talking about distributing something to people who may not have Node.js installed, meaning you probably can't rely on them being able perform a bunch of installs just to get to your app.

Answer (score 0):

[How to package and distribute your apps](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/how-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps) solved my problem!